# i want to remove the text before second last "." in a text file

Tags: linux

I have input file similar to this:

```
www.google.com
www.test.facebook.com
www.bing.com
www.m.facebook.com
```

... and i want output like this:

```
google.com
facebook.com
bing.com
facebook.com
```

Comment: Is the TLD always `.com`? What about `.co.uk`, `.com.au` etc?

Comment: What is the language you are using?  You can probably find existing code that does exactly what you want.

Comment: What have you try so far ? Which language do you want to use ? Please consider having a look a this page [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cat yourfile.txt | sed -ne "s/^.*\.\([^.]\+\.[^.]\+\)$/\1/p"
```

for example, this works for me:

```
<<EOF | sed -ne "s/^.*\.\([^.]\+\.[^.]\+\)$/\1/p"
www.google.com
www.test.facebook.com
www.bing.com
www.m.facebook.com
EOF
```

this will output:

```
google.com
facebook.com
bing.com
facebook.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Or an awk-version (I put your URLs in the file `domains`):

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{print $(NF-1),$NF}' domains
google.com
facebook.com
bing.com
facebook.com
```

Explanation: use `.` as a field-separator, print 2nd to last and last field.